# Plotting Character vector in R

Tags: r

I have the following 2 vectors of characters what can be a meaningful way of plotting the values

```
Observed_Value          Simulated_Value

   IP                      BP
   SP                      IP
   BP                      SP
   IP                      IP
```

Comment: Suposing you variable is `data`, this may be a good way: `plot(with(data, table(Observed_Value, Simulated_Value)))`. But if you explain better what are those values and what you want will be easier help you!

Comment: Hi , these are broker behavior where IP stands for idle position BP for Buying Position and Sp for selling position , and want to plot the observed value against the simulated value and see how much they vary

Comment: If there are really only 3 possible values, I would think that a table would be more informative than a graph, quite frankly.

Answer (score 3):

Well maybe you are interested in a heatmap, which displays how often a particular combination  appears:

```
library("plyr")
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(
  Observed  = sample(rep( c("IP", "SP", "BP"), 100 )),
  Simulated = sample(rep( c("IP", "SP", "BP"), 100 ))
)
counts <- ddply( df, c("Observed", "Simulated"), nrow )
names(counts)[3] <- "sum"
ggplot( counts, aes( x = Observed, y = Simulated, fill = sum ) ) + geom_tile()
```

[image]